# Strings resource file triggers "Namespace is not bound" when using build flavors

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, android-lint

If I take a project (apparently any project, in my experience at least), create a new flavor build variant, and copy the whole strings.xml file from the main/res source folder to the flavor's res folder, the build shows the "Namespace is not bound" error relating to the flavor's strings.xml file which is obviously exactly the same as the one in the main source folder. Android Lint does not show a warning for the main/res strings.xml.

In reality my project has a much smaller strings.xml file in the flavour res folder, but it still shows this Android Lint warning.

Is this a bug in Android Lint, or is there a real issue here and if so how do I correct it or suppress it if it's a false positive? Which namespace? Not bound to what?

I looked at the Android Lint checks documentation to see if there was more information about this Lint check but oddly it does not appear to be on the list of Lint checks: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tips/lint-checks